# Jackson+Spring3.0.5 custom object mapper

Tags: spring, jackson

I am having a hard time configuring Jackson on my Spring application. I can get it to work, but it does not seem to accept any kind of configurations. Basically what i'm trying to achieve is have an ObjectMapper that scans for Spring format annotations.

What i am trying is this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="ro.softwin.cnfp.ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass"
                    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                <property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
                <property name="objectMapper" value="jacksonObjectMapper" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The code for the mapper is :

```
public class ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
@Autowired
public ConversionServiceAwareObjectMapper(
        ConversionService conversionService) {
    AnnotationIntrospector introspector = AnnotationIntrospector.pair(
            new FormatAnnotationIntrospector(conversionService),
            DEFAULT_ANNOTATION_INTROSPECTOR);

    this.setDeserializationConfig(this.getDeserializationConfig()
            .withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector));
    this.setSerializationConfig(this.getSerializationConfig()
            .withAnnotationIntrospector(introspector).withSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL));

}
```

}

When initializing the server the following error occurs:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper] for property 'objectMapper': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:470)
    ... 55 more

I tried switching to a normal view resolver and just having the object mapper in the AnnotationMethodHandler, and that works regarding server start-up, but it just completely ignores any configuration.

I am completely at a loss as to what to do next.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update :

```
<property name="objectMapper" value="jacksonObjectMapper" />
```

with:

```
<property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
```

ref not value.