# REST API java class set initial value of setter getter if no data in database

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a rest api, i get the data using DAO, mapping it from class to another DTO class, if no data present in database, instead of returning null like this

```
{
"tes":null,
"tez": null,
"example": null
}
```

i want to return like this:

```
{
"tes":"",
"tez": "",
"example": ""
}
```

i have more than 100 field. so i think its not good to set value in setter getter in all field. how to do this is simple way?

Comment: Do you use ModelMapper ?

Comment: no. i map to java class using setter getter.

Comment: How you generate your json ?

Comment: springboot automatically generate json from class in @restcontroller

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have two options.

- Instead of manualy mapping from DAO to DTO Class you need to use a ModelMapper Class with

  `modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());`
- As your problem is not clearly the mapping but generating JSON from your DTO, you can use Jackson

  `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`

This will skip the empty/null values in your generated JSON.

See: [Spring REST Service: how to configure to remove null objects in json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707165/spring-rest-service-how-to-configure-to-remove-null-objects-in-json-response)

Comment: i dont want to exclude null. i want to change every null to " ". i tried use json include, still get null if no data in database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lombok like so

```
@Builder.Default
private String tes = "my-default-value";
```