# How to not return null value in ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

I use `ResponseEntity` to return response for a GET "api/v1/name" and POST "api/v1/name" request.

My goal is not to return response with null value, for example in a POST "api/v1/name" request, currently the response body would be:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "who",
    "newid": "A8C90A53-78F6-4BD6-9628-CBA8FC349C08"
}
```

What I wish it would look like:

```
{
    "name": "who",
    "newid": "A8C90A53-78F6-4BD6-9628-CBA8FC349C08"
}
```

In my opinion, recreating the object using this code below would only make the code less readable and maybe use more memory (I am not sure, please let me know if I am wrong):

```
...
Map<String, String> responseBody = new HashMap<>();
responseBody.put("name", nameModel.getName());
responseBody.put("newid", nameModel.getNewId());

return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);
```

==== Down below is the full repository, if you wish to see the updated one: https://github.com/kidfrom/g2_java/tree/main/etc/mssqlserver

controller/NameController.java

```
package com.example.mssqlserver.controller;

import com.example.mssqlserver.mapper.NameMapper;
import com.example.mssqlserver.model.NameModel;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class NameController {

  @Autowired
  private NameMapper nameMapper;

  @GetMapping("api/v1/name")
  public ResponseEntity<?> selectAll() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(nameMapper.selectAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }

  @PostMapping("api/v1/name")
  public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@RequestBody NameModel nameModel) {

    // validator
    if (!nameModel.requestIsValid()) {
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

    if (nameMapper.insert(nameModel) == 1) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(nameModel, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
  }
}
```

mapper/NameMapper.java

```
package com.example.mssqlserver.mapper;

import com.example.mssqlserver.model.NameModel;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;

import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface NameMapper {

  @Select("SELECT * FROM name")
  public List<NameModel> selectAll();

  @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT NEWID()", keyProperty = "newid", resultType = String.class, before = true)
  @Insert("INSERT INTO name (name, newid) VALUES (#{name}, #{newid})")
//  @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
  int insert(NameModel nameModel);
}
```

model/NameModel.java

```
package com.example.mssqlserver.model;

public class NameModel {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private String newid;

  public NameModel(Integer id, String name, String newid) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.newid = newid;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getNewid() {
    return newid;
  }

  public void setNewid(String newid) {
    this.newid = newid;
  }

  public boolean requestIsValid() {
    if (this.name.isEmpty()) return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` to `NameModel` at the class level

Comment: It appears that either you aren't using Spring Boot, or you're re-declaring things that come for free, because nulls would be suppressed by default. In either case, though, @DCTID's answer is the direct one.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I do use Spring Boot. Could you please clarify about `re-declaring things that come for free?`. If you may, would you like to give the example? I really appreciate it. Anyway, the code above is a sample code, no extra code is used, I also have ongoing project without a constructor defined yet show exact behavior `null is included in the response' https://github.com/kidfrom/g2_java/blob/main/Bank_Account/java/bankaccount/src/main/java/com/example/bankaccount/model/Transactions_ProgressModel.java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this simple solution could help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36515285/5108695

Since Jackson is being used, you have to configure that as a Jackson property. In the case of Spring Boot REST services, you have to configure it in application.properties or application.yml:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion = NON_NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot view https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/reference/htmlsingle
and search
`spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion`