# Exclude null properties from Spring Boot Rest controllers

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, httpresponse, spring-restcontroller

I have a rest service exposed using spring boot rest controller but with the response i'm sending object's properties those has null values.

For ex : ReponseEntity.ok(list) and that list consist of Objects A with lot of null properties.

Is there an easy way of excluding those null properties with spring boot tools?

Comment: Try using the jackson library and annotate your class with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring REST Service: how to configure to remove null objects in json response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707165/spring-rest-service-how-to-configure-to-remove-null-objects-in-json-response)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in application.properties file

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

Ref - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper

or you can try following annotation in class level or property level

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```